# How to create a list out of a json array

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

What i need to do is console.log all ip adresses and objects inside services and i have no idea what to do my current code is

```
    fetch('https://search.censys.io/api/v2/hosts/search?q=' + option1 + '&per_page=' + option2 + '&virtual_hosts=' + option3, fetchauth)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response.result.hits[0].ip))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

sample API response

https://pastebin.com/s7k2YLG5

Im planing to display these informations inside a discord embed

Comment: Can you post a json you need pls?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwidnOWCoaH5AhWZi_0HHQnfBz0QFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AOvVaw12XNJirv8-3J2POqmbqwb2) to get list of IPs:

```
response.result.hits.map(item => item.ip)
```

```js
const response = {
  "code": 200,
  "status": "OK",
  "result": {
    "query": "query",
    "total": 34,
    "duration": 1245,
    "hits": [
      {
        "ip": "x.x.x.x",
        "services": [
          {
            "port": 21,
            "service_name": "FTP",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "port": 22,
            "service_name": "SSH",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        "ip": "y.y.y.y",
        "services": [
          {
            "port": 80,
            "service_name": "HTTP",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "port": 443,
            "service_name": "HTTP",
            "certificate": "c3ea28c3a4eaa4075c45bb3740dd4207af099727eb654b974bb0b2a5703406b2",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          }
        ],
        "location": {
          "continent": "Europe",
          "country": "France",
          "country_code": "FR",
          "timezone": "Europe/Paris",
          "coordinates": {
            "latitude": 48.8582,
            "longitude": 2.3387
          },
          "registered_country": "France",
          "registered_country_code": "FR"
        },
        "autonomous_system": {
          "asn": 16276,
          "description": "OVH",
          "bgp_prefix": "51.38.0.0/16",
          "name": "OVH",
          "country_code": "FR"
        },
        "last_updated_at": "2022-07-29T12:59:03.142Z"
      }
]
}
};

console.log(response.result.hits.map(a=>a.ip));
```